# How to update multiple values in mysql based on another table using join

Tags: mysql, sql

I have two tables products and filters. My products table is like below:-

```
id    name    color_id    size_id    composition_id
 1    Test      Black     60x60 CM       Cotton
 2    Test2     Red       60X90 CM      Acryllic
```

My filters table as below:-

```
id    filter_name
 1      Black
 2      Red
 22     60x60 CM 
 23     60X90 CM
 61     Cotton
 62     Acryllic
```

My Expected output like below:-

```
id    name    color_id    size_id    composition_id
 1    Test       1            22           61
 2    Test2      2            23           62
```

I have tried below query that is working for only color_id. Query is below:-

```
UPDATE products
INNER JOIN filters ON products.color_id = filters.filter_name
SET products.color_id = filters.id
```

I want to update all ' color_id,size_id,composition_id' in one update statement. May be we need to use Case Statements. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way you can do this is with a set of correlated subqueries, one for each column that you need to look up. We use a `COALESCE` so that if the value is not found, we retain the previous value:

```
UPDATE products p
  SET color_id = COALESCE((SELECT id FROM filters WHERE filter_name = p.color_id), color_id),
      size_id = COALESCE((SELECT id FROM filters WHERE filter_name = p.size_id), size_id),
      composition_id = COALESCE((SELECT id FROM filters WHERE filter_name = p.composition_id), composition_id)
```

Then you can `SELECT * FROM products`:

```
id  name    color_id    size_id composition_id
1   Test    1           22      61
2   Test2   2           23      62
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/J31WKQEZqynBRsBkHARKw/1)

You can also achieve the same result with an `UPDATE ... JOIN` query, which might be more efficient:

```
UPDATE products p
LEFT JOIN filters f1 ON f1.filter_name = p.color_id
LEFT JOIN filters f2 ON f2.filter_name = p.size_id
LEFT JOIN filters f3 ON f3.filter_name = p.composition_id
SET color_id = COALESCE(f1.id, color_id),
    size_id = COALESCE(f2.id, size_id),
    composition_id = COALESCE(f3.id, composition_id)
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/J31WKQEZqynBRsBkHARKw/2)

Comment: Your way is right but what if my 100 records are already updated  and i again run this query... above 100 records will be empty .. Hope you understand

Comment: @kunal I didn't realise you might run the query multiple times. I've updated it (and the demo) for that situation

Comment: actually my client don't want to fill ids in column.. So my client gives csv sheet with names every week so i will update the sql query manually . Hope you understand

Comment: @kunal I can't say I blame them - much easier to write the words! But the new queries I have posted should do what you want.

Comment: Yes Nick we can't blame them but we need to follow the protocols of mysql for saving id in column ... I will check and let you know if its working fine or not

Comment: its working fine.. i will follow your 2nd query thanks a lot :)

Comment: what is meaning of this COALESCE ?

Comment: [`COALESCE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce) looks at each of its arguments, starting from the left, and returns the first one that is not `NULL`. So for example, in the second query, if there is no match for `color_id` in `filters`, `f1.id` will be `NULL` and the `COALESCE(f1.id, color_id)` will return the original value of `color_id`